# Accessing sparse matrix elements

Tags: scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a very large sparse matrix of the type 'scipy.sparse.coo.coo_matrix'. I can convert to csr with .tocsr(), however .todense() will not work since the array is too large. I want to be able to extract elements from the matrix as I would do with a regular array, so that I may pass row elements to a function.

For reference, when printed, the matrix looks as follows:

```
(7, 0)  0.531519363001
(48, 24)    0.400946334437
(70, 6) 0.684460955022
...
```

Comment: The `csr` format accepts indexing just like dense arrays (though not quite as fast).  The `coo` format does not.  For whole rows you many want to do `M1=M.tocsr(); row = M1[i,:].A` (`toarray()`) assuming the function expects a dense array.

Comment: How would you pull out, for example, the three numbers at the top of my print ((7, 0)  0.531519363001)?
I don't know what the .A does in your example, but if I skip that part I get a long row of [0 0 0 ... 0]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make a matrix with 3 elements:

```
In [550]: M = sparse.coo_matrix(([.5,.4,.6],([0,1,2],[0,5,3])), shape=(5,7))
```

It's default display (`repr(M)`):

```
In [551]: M
Out[551]: 
<5x7 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

and print display (str(M)) - looks like the input:

```
In [552]: print(M)
  (0, 0)    0.5
  (1, 5)    0.4
  (2, 3)    0.6
```

convert to `csr` format:

```
In [553]: Mc=M.tocsr()
In [554]: Mc[1,:]   # row 1 is another matrix (1 row):
Out[554]: 
<1x7 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [555]: Mc[1,:].A    # that row as 2d array
Out[555]: array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.4,  0. ]])

In [556]: print(Mc[1,:])    # like 2nd element of M except for row number
  (0, 5)    0.4
```

Individual element:

```
In [560]: Mc[1,5]
Out[560]: 0.40000000000000002
```

The data attributes of these format (if you want to dig further)

```
In [562]: Mc.data
Out[562]: array([ 0.5,  0.4,  0.6])
In [563]: Mc.indices
Out[563]: array([0, 5, 3], dtype=int32)
In [564]: Mc.indptr
Out[564]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3], dtype=int32)
In [565]: M.data
Out[565]: array([ 0.5,  0.4,  0.6])
In [566]: M.col
Out[566]: array([0, 5, 3], dtype=int32)
In [567]: M.row
Out[567]: array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: How can I extract the two numbers associated with the individual element that I get from Mc[1,5] (in this case (0,5) if I'm not mistaken)?

Comment: I think rdist.row[i], rdist.col[i] would get the numbers I want.

Answer (score 0):

We can convert a `scipy.sparse.coo_array` to a `pandas.DataFrame`.

Utility function:

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_array
import pandas as pd


def coo_to_dataframe(array: coo_array) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Convert scipy COO sparse array to a pandas data frame."""
    labels = array.data
    columns = array.col
    rows = array.row

    data_frame = pd.DataFrame({"x": columns, "y": rows, "label": labels})

    return data_frame
```

Create a sparse array (borrowed from @hpaulj):

```
sparse_array = coo_array(([.5, .4, .6], ([0 , 1, 2], [0, 5, 3])), shape=(5, 7))
```

For a small example array, we can view it as a dense array:

```
sparse_array.toarray()

array([[0.5, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0.4, 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0.6, 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ]])
```

Finally, we convert the sparse array to a DataFrame and plot it.

```
dataframe = coo_to_dataframe(sparse_array)

dataframe.plot.scatter("x", "y", title="Sparse labels")
```

[image: Sparse labels plot]